# Select Random from 3 Million rows

Tags: mysql, random

I have 3.2 million rows with a few keys to help speed up the sorting. However, as my table grows, things are getting slow and slower each day. Can you guys please take a look at my query and let me know if there are any other solutions I can have to make this process quicker better?

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT `numbers` FROM `avotf`.`master` WHERE `active`=1 order by `monthly_mins`,`called`,`added`,rand() limit 200) AS T1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `ORDER BY rand()`, that's the issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4329396/1409082) and [Getting random results from large tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12356733/1409082)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your table has a numeric `id` column, something like this should work (borrowed from [here](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/)):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
 WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

Do **not** do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

It works but it will be extremely slow

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you use RAND() with lots of data

You should read the following blog post of Jan Kneschke: [ORDER BY RAND()](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)

He lists a few possible solutions and their performance behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's well known that `ORDER BY RAND()` can be very slow, and while you've tried to select against a subselect here, that still creates a temporary table.

It's not clear why you select `RAND()` in the subselect, then ignore this and create a new sort key on the outer select. Maybe you could make use of that.

Your `ORDER BY` conditions are quite extensive, and if you're missing an index there then it'll be row-scans to get them all.

Don't forget to `EXPLAIN` your query.